# setting up laravel 5.2 in a sub doamin at a shared hosting server

Tags: php, deployment, laravel-5

I want to deploy laravel 5.2 into a sub domain named sub but i get the following error

> Unable to handle the request
>   HTTP ERROR 50

I have researhed and found that i require php version 5.5.9 and above in order for laravel to run. I have laravel 5.5, but When i place laravel "public" folder contents into the shared host "public_html" folder it works but when i place the same content into my sub domain its not working.

i have also changed the index.php as follows

```
require __DIR__.'/../sub/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../sub/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

After you [meet the server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements), You only need to point your subdomain to the `public` directory of your laravel project directory.

e.g. if your domain is `enaveed.com`, your subdomain is `flipflop.enaveed.com` and your project is in `/public_html/flipflop` directory, this is how you need to configure your subdomain in a standard cpanel environment:

[image: Standard cpanel view]

Comment: Hi Engr Naveed, I already configured the subdomain to point to public_html folder using cpanel but i am getting the same error message.

Comment: Do not point to `public_html`. Place the whole project folder somewhere as it is. And then point to the `public` directory of your laravel project. You don't need to change the directory structure or any php file (including `index.php`). Revert the changes if you made any.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should met the server requirement:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements

Second, you should upload all the files of laravel into your public_html

Third, change the name of server.php to index.php

fourth, copy .htaccess file from laravel "public" folder to your public_html

Answer (score 0):

```
require __DIR__.'/../sub/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../sub/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Those paths look wrong.

- First, Copy everything except public folder in your root
  folder(preferably not in public_html but one level up, so people
  cannot access them) and give a name to folder. Let's say the folder
  name is laravel.
- Copy your public folder in to your public folder(public_html), then, rename it to "sub". So you can access it by http://www.yourwebsite.com/sub.
- in **index.html** file in your **sub** folder, change the paths like below.

  require **DIR**.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
  $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

  - Go to bootstrap/app.php file, then change below

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
  realpath(**DIR**.'/../')
);

to

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
  realpath(__DIR__.'/../../laravel/')
);
```

- Go to **Bootstrap/autoload.php** file and change

  require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
```

It should work now.
(P.S. I don't like this markdown typing. it shows some of my codes in block but does not some of them)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i should access the sub-domain content in  http://www.sub.yourwebsite.com